# My mergesort code is having problems with recursion?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

```
def mergesort(A, left, right):  # Input size is n
    if left == right:
        return
    mid = (left + right)//2
    mergesort(A,left, mid)
    mergesort(A, mid, right)
    merge(A, left, mid, right)
    
def merge(A, left, mid, right):
    L = A[left:mid+1]
    R = A[mid+1:right]
    lp = 0 
    rp = 0 
    start_p = 0
    while lp < len(L) and rp < len(R):
        if L[lp] < R[rp]:
            A[start_p] = L[lp]
            start_p += 1
            lp += 1
        else:
            A[start_p] = R[rp]
            start_p += 1
            rp += 1
    while lp < len(L):
        A[start_p] = L[lp]
        start_p += 1
        lp += 1
    while rp < len(R):
        A[start_p] = R[rp]
        start_p += 1
        rp += 1
    return
```

When I run the code, it always says "maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison" but I I have the stopping criterion here. I don't know where the problem lies :/

Comment: I didn't go through all code, but the first thing that draws attention is that you're including `mid` in both recursive calls. it should be `mergesort(A, left, mid)` and `mergesort(A, mid+1, right)`

Comment: @mangusta, I don't think that is an issue. The code treats the last argument given to `mergesort` as index *beyond* the intended range, much like native functions do in Python.

Answer (score 2):

I understand from your code that `right` represents the index *beyond* the range, like is the common habit in Python.

There are three issues:

- The base case should be when you only have 1 element in the range. This happens when `left == right + 1`, so your first `if` condition is wrong. With `left == right` you will get an infinite recursion, because a 1-sized range will be split into a zero-sized range and... a 1-sized range. And so that second one will be the cause of yet another recursive call, ...etc. So change the `if` condition to `left + 1 >= right`.
- The first statements in `merge` split up the ranges at `mid+1`, while this should be `mid`.
- Two statements later you assign 0 to `start_p`, but remember that `merge` is called with a range: `left`, `right`. Using index 0 means that later on you will *write* a value in `A[0]`, which could be out of the given range. It should be `left`, not 0.

So with those three issues corrected, the working code becomes:

```
def mergesort(A, left, right):
    if left + 1 >= right:
        return
    mid = (left + right)//2
    mergesort(A, left, mid)
    mergesort(A, mid, right)
    merge(A, left, mid, right)
    
def merge(A, left, mid, right):
    L = A[left:mid]
    R = A[mid:right]
    lp = 0 
    rp = 0 
    start_p = left  # !!
    while lp < len(L) and rp < len(R):
        if L[lp] < R[rp]:
            A[start_p] = L[lp]
            start_p += 1
            lp += 1
        else:
            A[start_p] = R[rp]
            start_p += 1
            rp += 1
    while lp < len(L):
        A[start_p] = L[lp]
        start_p += 1
        lp += 1
    while rp < len(R):
        A[start_p] = R[rp]
        start_p += 1
        rp += 1
```

Comment: Could you give some feed-back to this answer?